# "States" in javascript or php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, apache-flex

I've been working with FLEX for while and I had there some "states" declaration. For those who are not sure what I mean, it's like a couple of different pages between you can translate, setting a current state.
Now I want to get started with Facebook development, and I don't know how to pass between pages I created with html. I guess that would be possible using javascript rather than php, but I am not sure how. Can someone please help me?

A scheme of what I would like to do is:

```
              tigger1  
State A-------------------->State B

              trigger2      
State B-------------------->State C
```

The following example shows a login panel with 2 states: `default`, for showing the login  form, and `Register` for showing the form for registration. The current state change is triggered by an action (in this case, pressing the `Linkbutton`). Mainly, what states do, is displaying proper content based on what the user should be able to do under each state. So, if for example I want to do a payment form, after the user attempts to make the payment, if the payment was successfully done, I would have a "Thank_you" state, while if the payment failed, I would have a "Try_again" state. How can this be done using php/js?

Code sample of [login/register panel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7dd4) (from adobe flex website, also running example and full code can be found in the link):

```
<!-- The Application class states property defines the view states.-->
<s:states>
    <s:State name="default"/>    
    <s:State name="Register"/>
</s:states>

<!-- Set title of the Panel container based on the view state.-->
<s:Panel id="loginPanel" 
    title="Login" title.Register="Register">     

    <s:Form id="loginForm">
        <s:FormItem label="Username:">
            <s:TextInput/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Password:">
            <s:TextInput/>
        </s:FormItem>


        <s:FormItem id="confirm" label="Confirm:" includeIn="Register">
            <!-- Add a TextInput control to the form ONLY for the Register view state. -->           
            <s:TextInput/>
        </s:FormItem>            

        <s:FormItem>            
            <!-- Use the LinkButton to change view state.-->
                <!-- Set label of the control based on the view state.-->
                <mx:LinkButton id="registerLink"
                    label="Need to Register?" 
                    label.Register="Return to Login"
                    click="currentState="Register"
                    click.Register="currentState="default"/>
                <s:Button id="loginButton" 
                    label="Login" label.Register="Register"/>
        </s:FormItem>            
    </s:Form>
</s:Panel>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having a problem understanding the question/problem.  Can you break it down a bit more, maybe include some sample code?

Comment: I can provide some flex code if you would like to, and i'll try to brake it down a bit more, but I can't provide any php/javascript code simply because i don't know how I should do it in php/javascript

Comment: Would you expand on this a bit more? _[State] is like a couple of different pages between you can translate, setting a current state_. What is it you want to pass between pages? (Supplying a **short** piece of Flex code may be of assistance, but try to describe it in English too).

Comment: @halfer I have added some sample code, and if you click on the link, the example will explain better than I can

Comment: Someone has kindly provided further clarifications as to what you mean by "states" - if you want to get other answers to the question, it's fine to unaccept it for a couple of days (I think this is possible).

Comment: @halfer Thanks a lot, I will edit by your suggestions, also, I will try to explain better how states work. I'm quite new here, and also explaining things seem not to be my key ability, as you probably already seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I think I understand your question. Flex (or Flash) works with ongoing variables (or states) because it is a long-running program, controlled by events from a user interface.

Web programming isn't like that. Each page is served separately, from a program that lives only for the duration of that request, and so state has to be maintained on the client side by the use of cookies. Since the server often needs to be aware of user state, the cookie (if one is set) is supplied by the browser to the server automatically, who can cross-reference the cookie's value with things that this user has done before.

If the cookie value is unique, it can be used to cross-reference a session store, which is a set of values just for one user. PHP offers this inside its `$_SESSION` feature. This is quite a big topic in itself, so I would recommend web-searching for "PHP session examples" - here and on the web - and playing with some code. Real examples will show you how it all works.

Edit: turns out states (variables) and states (UI variants) are different things! See the comments for more details.

Comment: I've looking inside some code for facebook login and I saw this just before some html code written, and looking at the webpage, i realized it was just that kind of state change I was talking about. It was `if(isset($basic))` - html code-. I think this checks if the user is logged in, but I am not 100% sure. So, can things be done in such a way?
P.S. Thanks, I'll take a look at `$_SESSION`

Comment: +1.  I don't think this answers the question; but I think it's a good attempt to do so as the poster didn't provide a satisfactory explanation of what states are.  States are like variants on a page.  As one example; when searching for support documents on a computer manufacturer site.  You may first select the type of computer you have (Say, an HP Pavillion).  (That would be state1).  Upon selecting; a second select box shows up allowing you to choose your model number (ZD7000). That would be state2.  Finally; a third select box allows you to choose operating system.  That would be state3.

Comment: States, in Flex, are often used to make these little tweaks to the screen/page in response to user interaction.

Comment: @Mihai, yes you can do this. Render all the controls you need in HTML, and use a JavaScript layer (say jQuery) to handle events that show/hide/modify elements as required. I suspect the feature in Flex you're used to provides more framework around this - perhaps there are JS UI libraries that do a similar thing.